# How to automatically make symbols in equations less crowded?

Tags: math-mode, equations, symbols, amsmath, mathtools

[image]

As you can see in the pic above, some parts of the equation seem to be crowded. Here, the problem is fixed by using `\thinspace` command. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
%
    V_{oc} = V_{oc,ref} \bigg[1 + \frac{\beta}{100} (T_{op}-T_{ref}) \biggl] + V_{oc,ref} \thinspace \varphi \thinspace ln \bigg( \frac{G_{op}}{G_{ref}} \bigg)
%
\label{eq:V_oc_trans}
\end{equation}


\begin{equation}
%
V_{oc} = V_{oc,ref} \bigg[1 + \frac{\beta}{100} (T_{op}-T_{ref}) \biggl] + V_{oc,ref} \varphi ln \bigg( \frac{G_{op}}{G_{ref}} \bigg)
%
\label{eq:V_oc_trans2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Which returns:

The problem here is that typing `\thinspace` over and over is redundant. Can we overcome crowdedness by writing some command in the preamble or using a package option?

Comment: the main problem is that you should not use math italic for multi-letter words (it spreads them out to make them not look like a word) use `T_{\mathrm{ref}}` and the same for `op` and `oc`

Comment: also you should use `\biggl` on the left and `\biggr` on the right (although I would use a smaller size here)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

After looking at the equation, I see just one place where a thin space is needed, namely in front of `\varphi`. Note that the thin space is denoted by `\,`.

However, the subscript should be all `\mathrm`, because they're textual; `\bigg` should be either `\biggl` (opening) or `\biggr` (closing); `ln` should be `\ln`. The parentheses around the argument of the logarithm, which is a fraction, are not needed.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:V_oc_trans}
V_{\mathrm{oc}} =
V_{\mathrm{oc},\mathrm{ref}}
  \biggl[1 + \frac{\beta}{100} (T_{\mathrm{op}}-T_{\mathrm{ref}}) \biggr] +
V_{\mathrm{oc},\mathrm{ref}} \, \varphi \ln \frac{G_{\mathrm{op}}}{G_{\mathrm{ref}}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The position of `\label` is actually immaterial, but placing it at the beginning helps to see it more easily.

[image]

Switching the position of `\varphi` may be another choice; this doesn't require `\,`:

[image]